# Problem with booting ubuntu 14.10 when using tmpfs for /tmp

Tags: ssd, tmpfs

I was following the recommendation on this page: http://yktoo.com/en/blog/post/id/233

Apparently when I put my `/tmp` to `tmpfs` then the system cannot boot. It seems that the booting runs into some loop as the services stop and start again and again.

Has someone got the same experience?